# Pivot a row into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

So, I have a table that show the version of an application for a server.
Checking for each server, each version of each application.
Im using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
Basically this is what my table look like right now :

```
|   Application   |   Server    | Version |
---------------------------------------
|  Application_1  |  Server_1   |   420   | 
|  Application_1  |  Server_2   |   410   |
|  Application_1  |  Server_3   |   420   | 
|  Application_2  |  Server_1   |   18    |
|  Application_2  |  Server_2   |   19    |
|  Application_2  |  Server_3   |   18    |
```

and I would like to pivot it to summary **per** application. So something like that :

```
|  Application  | Server_1 | Server_2 | Server_3 |   
---------------------------------------
| Application_1 |    420   |    410   |    420   |
| Application_2 |    18    |    19    |    18    |
```

I searched in previous topics about pivot, looked into forums and tutorials, but still not able to find out how to use it.
Any help would be really appreciate, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE ([Application] VARCHAR(50),  [Server] VARCHAR(50) ,[Version] INT)
INSERT INTO @TBL VALUES
('Application_1','Server_1',420),
('Application_1','Server_2',410),
('Application_1','Server_3',420),
('Application_2','Server_1',18),
('Application_2','Server_2',19),
('Application_2','Server_3',18);

SELECT * FROM @TBL
PIVOT
(
SUM([Version]) FOR [Server] IN ([Server_1],[Server_2],[Server_3])
) PV
```

Comment: Simple solution thanx

Comment: Your solution fit the problem exactly how I needed it to be, and the way you do it make it easier for me to understand!
Thanks a lot @JonWay